# Flat file, text parsing, string methods

Tags: ruby, string, parsing, methods

I am new to ruby and I am trying out Programming Ruby-The Pragmatic Programmer's Guide. I am trying to use some String class methods in order to create song objects based on a song list that is stored as rows on a flat file:

My two questions are:
1. How do I create my song list in a flat file? 
2. How would a get ruby to run and understand that particular file?

Thanks

Comment: What is the format of the file?  What values are you string in it? We need lots more information to be helpful.

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html CSV parsing may be all you need.

Comment: maybe regular expressions or "String#split" will help...

Comment: it seems you new to programming also, i suggest you to try learn to program by Chris Pine or [learn ruby the hard way](http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/book/)

theres also a extensive list of resources here on [hacker_news](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2456994)

Comment: Since you are exercising approaches, rather than solving a little-solved problem, I recommend writing a draft code and submit it to codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Keep a text file of your songs.

```
Westfall
I Am the Walrus
Hey Jude
```

Open the file.

```
$song_file = open('songs.txt')
```

Create an empty list of songs.

```
$song_list = []
```

Iterate through each line of your text file creating objects with the information from the file and adding them to your list.

```
$song_file.each_line do |line|
    $song_list << Song.new(line)
end
```

Now you have your song objects.

If you want to know more about using file I/O in Ruby look at the documentation.
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html